# Confused on graphics rendering

Tags: rendering, camera, projection, viewport

Implementing a viewport is just a rectangular space on the back buffer usually a 2d texture set to the size of the client window that we render to.

However in direct3d when we describe the viewport it asks for the window width and heights and the top left X,Y position

From what I understand normalized device coordinates for the top left would be represented by 1,-1 and if I chose another type of device coordinate would be represented by 0 , 0.

How does this translate To a coordinate system for primitives I draw on screen from some file formats like wavefronts OBJ format their are coordinates that are out of range from -1 to 1.

[image]

Comment: Hint: you're never drawing just the model. You're drawing a *view* of the model, from a specific *perspective*.

Comment: but is the “true” “world” I’m rendering my model to the coordinates that make up my back buffer (the height and width) of my window or is it the (in direct3d) the top left XY coordinate system that range from 0 to 1. Maybe I’m misunderstanding.

Comment: Neither. Those are measures of the canvas the artist is painting on, not measures of the scenery the artist is painting.

Comment: So does the primitives sent in through the pipeline get converted to pixel coordinates that make up the width and height of my window and get mapped there during the rasterization stage ?

Comment: It sounds like you're skipping a few pipeline stages. Wouldn't that be the job of the vertex shader stage?